# A lot of missing dependencies when I try to install all software

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation

I have problem with missing dependencies, when I try to install some software by apt-get and also from downloaded .deb files.

I am using Debian 10. After installation I removed a lot of software which I no needed eg. Deluge, some terminals (I have only LXTerminal now), some tools from Libre Office Packet etc.

Now, when I try to install Atom, TeamViewer, or some RDP tools, every time I got information about missing unresolved dependencies, common it is `libgconf`, `libcurl` etc.

How can I resolve this issue? Now I can not install a lot of must have software, and when I try to `apt-get install` this packets, I got error, that no libs with this name were found.

Here is my sources.list. Maybe it will be some tip to fix this problem:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates non-free contrib main deb-src 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates non-free contrib main deb-src 

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports non-free contrib main 

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
```

Stretch repos were added for test purposes, but when I comment them, it looks the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the main Debian 10 repository to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster non-free contrib main
```

You should also remove the Debian 9 lines (Stretch).

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the "unneded packages" by using the package manager, installing ones that do need them should install them again from the distribution's repositories..

Comment: Except when the repositories are no longer configured in the package manager’s list of known repositories.